# Jupyter Notebook is broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I tried to open jupyter notebook as usual, but suddenly I got this.
Notebook is broken and when type in codes, it behaves awkwardly; it returns many times and then finally the code will be written in cell.
Can anyone solve this? Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes I tried that but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your jupyter server is working really slowly. I've run into this before, and usually a host restart or reinstalling jupyter works for me.

Comment: thank you for answering. I deleted and reinstall jupyter, but it didn't change the situation.

Comment: Are you running it on a remote server? Maybe that is the case?

Comment: yeah I load it by `$ jupyter notebook` command and i think it is running on remote server. Is there any other way to run?